# Why when several users press a button in ReplyKeyboardMarkup() simultaneously, messages appear from both user only in one user?

Tags: multithreading, py-telegram-bot-api

Hi? tomorrow I find kind of a bug in my bot, so when two user, trying press a button in ReplyKeyboardMarkup() at one time, my bot send messages in one chat in double way (like to both user (In the logging console, it say it coming from the same ID value )),but another user don't get messages at all.

I think I need to creating some sort of multithreading things using threading lib or maybe there is some functions in pyTelegramBotApi for that task ??

```
import telebot
from telebot.async_telebot import AsyncTeleBot
from telebot.async_telebot import types
import asyncio
import logging
from hello_message import hello_message
logger = telebot.logger
telebot.logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
telebot.threading
bot = AsyncTeleBot(TOKEN)

def start_page_markup():
    reply_markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1)
    faces_choose = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Choose your face", callback_data="face_choose")
    reply_markup.add(faces_choose)
    return reply_markup

def faces_markup():
    reply_markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1)
    one_button = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="☹️", callback_data="sad")
    two_button = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="", callback_data="smile")
    reply_markup.add(one_button,two_button)
    return reply_markup

def chear_up_sad_markup():         
    reply_markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True, row_width=1)
    q1 = types.KeyboardButton("Click here")
    reply_markup.add(q1) 
    return reply_markup

@bot.message_handler(commands=["start"])
async def start(message):
    await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Hello my friend", reply_markup = start_page_markup())

@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
async def callback_inline(call):
    if call.message:
        # Techical page problem
        if call.data == "face_choose":
            await bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, "I'm watting....", reply_markup = faces_markup())
        ## Create the FAQ for internet problem page
        elif call.data == "sad":
            await bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, 'Why are u sad ????', reply_markup=chear_up_sad_markup())
            @bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: True)
            async def vpn_problem_page_faq(message):
                # Question 1
                if message.text == "Click here":
                    await bot.send_message(chat_id=call.message.chat.id, text="Nooooooo..... Don't be sad !!!")
                    await bot.send_message(chat_id=call.message.chat.id, text="You are smart, cute, strong badass !!!!!") 
        elif call.data == "smile":
            await bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, 'You are cute, smile more !!!')
if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(bot.polling())
```

This problem happened first in sync Telebot, so I taught that is the problem of sync version, so i created async version of bot, but problems is still up.

But when pressing a button in inlineKeyboardMarkup() at one time from both user, this problem doesn't happened.

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove `call.` mentioning in these lines:

```
if message.text == "Click here":
    await bot.send_message(chat_id=call.message.chat.id, text="Nooooooo..... Don't be sad !!!")
    await bot.send_message(chat_id=call.message.chat.id, text="You are smart, cute, strong badass !!!!!")
```

and use only `message.chat.id` since your function takes `message` parameter but not a `call`.